# How to simulate cable pull for Openstack VM?

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

we want to simulate a link state down in a Openstack Nova VM.
When we did "`openstack port set --disable <port>`" VM not sensing it.

Is there any way to bring down a VM port link, But keep the Admin state up?

Comment: Do you want to bring it so down, that even ARP-packages can not reach the VM anymore or is blocking of layer 3 enough for your test?

Comment: In "Ifconfig" or "ip link show", the output should show Port is UP buy link is down. Just like the cable disconnect in real machines. What I need is a physical layer down but protocol layer is up.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there seems to be such a feature in Openstack to do this since pike-version:

https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/neutron-specs/specs/pike/port-data-plane-status.html

which add the new CLI-option:

`openstack port set [--data-plane-status <ACTIVE/DOWN>] <port>`

there are some things necessary to activate this, which a written in the ticket of the feature:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1598081/comments/15

I tried it out on my test-deployment, but there was still a data-connection possible within the subnet. Maybe I've overlooked something or understand something wrong about this feature, but maybe it helps you.

The only other solution I have in mind, would it be to access the compute-node of the VM over ssh and take the tap-device down with `ip link set down <TAP_DEVICE>`, which represents the interface outside of the VM.